# Flutter with flavors not building to iOS

Tags: android, ios, flutter, build, android-flavors

Goody day,

When building to android I have no issues with using the flavors.

This is not the case for iOS, I receive the following error:

**Finished with error: Exception: Source directory "/Users/[HOME]/[PROJECT]/build/ios/Release-iphonesimulator/Runner.app" does not exist, nothing to copy**

Please see flutter doctor -v:

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E266, locale en-ZA)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.9 at /Users/[HOME]/flutter
    • Framework revision f139b11009 (4 days ago), 2020-03-30 13:57:30 -0700
    • Engine revision af51afceb8
    • Dart version 2.7.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/[HOME]/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/[HOME]/Library/Android/sdk
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = /Users/[HOME]/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.4)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.4, Build version 11E146
    • CocoaPods version 1.9.1

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 44.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554                        • android-x86 • Android 5.1.1 (API 22) (emulator)
    • iPhone 11 Pro Max         • 96D35F20-F138-40BA-BC95-0DF38DFCA21E • ios         • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-4 (simulator)

• No issues found!

Comment: This depends on how you added the Flavors to your iOS project. You did not provide any information so nobody can help you.

Comment: If you changed the Display Name of your project, that might be causing your issue. Check this link: https://medium.com/@animeshjain/build-flavors-in-flutter-android-and-ios-with-different-firebase-projects-per-flavor-27c5c5dac10b

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to configure a custom scheme to define flavors for the iOS build. From the error you've received, it seems that the build is non-existent. Follow this [guide](https://medium.com/@animeshjain/build-flavors-in-flutter-android-and-ios-with-different-firebase-projects-per-flavor-27c5c5dac10b#e801) to configure the custom scheme for your iOS build's flavor.